# Square root of a difference of two terms squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In finding the equation of a parabola given the focus/directrix, I'm given as an example the square root of the distance formula
$$\sqrt{(x_0-a)^2+(y_0-b)^2}=|y_0-c|$$
when the square root is evaluated the resultant equation is
$$(x_0-a)^2+(y_0-b)^2=(y_0-c)^2$$
I'm wondering why the expression $(x_0-a)$ remains squared in this simplification.

Comment: You are squaring both sides, so the sqrt on the left is gone, but what remains? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't remain squared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt{(x_{0}-a)^{2}+(y_{0}-b)^{2}}=|y_{0}-c|$

so squaring both sides gives

$\bigg(\sqrt{(x_{0}-a)^{2}+(y_{0}-b)^{2}}\bigg)^{2}=|y_{0}-c|^{2}$

so

$(x_{0}-a)^{2}+(y_{0}-b)^{2}=(y_{o}-c)^{2}$.

Only the outer square root is affected by squaring both sides. This is why the term $(x_{0}-a)$ remains squared.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help.